# ResponsiveSlides doesn't display pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm using ResponsiveSlides to make a slide of some pictures, but i have some issues.
First of all, automatic slide after a timeout doesn't work..
But my first problem is that i can't see the pager under the pictures, though i've enabled it! The pager is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKtZ8.png (the number of the picture under the slide)
Sorry for my english and sorry i'm a noob on js & css..

This is my html code:

Head:

```
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#slider").responsiveSlides({
auto: false,
pager: true,
speed: 300,
maxwidth: 540,
});
});
</script>
```

Css:

```
/*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */

.rslides {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
width: 90%;
padding: 0;
margin: 55px;
top: -50px;
}

.rslides li {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
 display: none;
 width: 90%;
 left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.rslides img {
 display: block;
height: auto;
float: left;
width: 90%;
border: 0;
}
```

Slider on my html page:

```
 <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
<li><img  src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
 </ul>
```

Why i dont see the pager?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I have more css and js files in local, how can i make it?

Comment: Mock up the relevant code needed to display your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XRay437/32Srd/ check here..

Comment: You must be missing something in your fiddle. Because it's not working  atm. I [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Grevling/32Srd/2/) the fiddle to make it work (a bit). If you can update it some more, I think we can resolve this :)

Comment: Ok thanks i'll use your fiddle to solve my problem ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out why yet but if you switch the order in which you reference your external scripts, it fixes the issue.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

The page links are unformatted "ul > li > a" so to get the appearance of the ResponsiveSlides website, you need to add your own CSS or modify theirs.